# Delphi: how to show up to 4 subpanels as grid

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I look for a way in Delphi 7 to have on TPanel 1 to 4 panels/cells as a grid. So I can show N x M cells grid, where N*M is 1 to 4. Each cell is resizable by a splitter, each cell should contain my custom TPanel or TFrame or whatever. How can I do it?

.NET has special component.
Does Delphi has such a component too?

Do I need to implement it by hand, ie make 4 panels / 3 splitters, and perform align assignments?

Comment: TGridPanel was introduced in D2007, if I remember correctly. So with D7, you are out of luck.

Comment: You might want to try [DictaSoft Layout Pack v.1.0](http://www.torry.net/pages.php?s=79). Description says it's a replacement for TGridPanel and that it comes with source.

Comment: Even `TGridPanel` wouldn't fit your requirement since it doesn't have splitter support for cells, rows nor cols.